# Heat Pump only heating for a few mins

Tags: hvac, heating, central-heating, heat-pump

I have a heatpump that will only run for a few mins before shutting off, inside blower runs nonstop. Cycles on again in about 45-60mins.(vent blows out warm air the first few mins then room temp air till it cycles again)
Outside temp is 45-50 Degrees F
Inside is 64 and thermostat is set at 65 on Heat (after an hour or so inside temp will fall to 63/62 and the Aux heat turns on).
Filter was replaced 2 weeks ago

Is this something I need a technician to come in and check out

Comment: Welcome! I can think of many possibilities which directly involve the  refrigerant system itself. I would recommend getting a pro. Before calling be sure the switch over thermostat is set high enough. Maybe bumping it up a few degrees will solve your problem.

Comment: @GIl, bumping it up a few degrees would only serve to engage the aux heat.  That wouldn't fix the issue of the heat pump not functioning properly.  Maybe list out some of the refrigerant-related possibilities in an answer?  "You need specialized refrigerant equipment/license to try X and Y and can't DIY it" is a valid answer for those scenarios.

Comment: Is frost or ice forming on the outside coils?

Comment: My mom's was doing the same thing many years ago. Changing the crossover point resolved it. It was spending its time in defrost. It ran until she passed without any more problems. That was a few years ago. If it does not fix it no damage, that is why I said maybe. No idea of what unit is there, age etc. Also there is no indication the OP has the required licenced so I did not mention refrigerant etc or where in this wide world it is located.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. There are a number of mechanical and electrical problems which can cause this, some of which are inexpensive to resolve and some of which are quite costly to fix. Call in a well reviewed company if you don't already have one that does your annual. If they give you a quote that includes anything like a total replacement and the unit is less than fifteen years old, consider getting a second opinion.

Comment: thanks for the reply, they system is only 5 yrs old and last summer when i purchased the house I had to have a tech charge they system with 2.5# to make it cool properly. Maybe this has something to do with that (possible leakage).

Comment: Entirely possible. The system should go the entire lifespan without needing additional refrigerant. Since it needed an addition, there's a leak. Hopefully the tech that did it was smart enough to put in some dye at the same time.